# How to set if only condition for duplicate rows

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataset of duplicate genes which looks like:

```
Gene        Score   V1  V2    ID
PABPC4  0.797203779 NA  NA  rs111768751
PABPC4  0.797203779 NA  NA  rs2068663
PABPC4  0.797203779 NA  NA  NA
ACE     0.897203779 NA  NA  rs61781371
ACE     0.897203779 NA  NA  rs11206374
BRCA    0.897203779 NA  NA  NA
BRCA    0.897203779 NA  NA  NA
```

I am trying to select and remove only the duplicate genes which only have 'NA' for IDs

Output:

```
BRCA    0.897203779 NA  NA  NA
BRCA    0.897203779 NA  NA  NA
```

I'm not sure how to set this condition, so far I've been using `filter()` but this gives me other genes which have a mix of NA and values in the ID column (e.g. for this example I am also picking up PABPC4 which I don't want). How can I write a condition for this selection?

Example input data:

```
structure(list(Gene = c("PABPC4", "PABPC4", "PABPC4", "ACE", 
"ACE", "BRCA", "BRCA"), Score = c(0.797203779, 0.797203779, 0.797203779, 
0.897203779, 0.897203779, 0.897203779, 0.897203779), V1 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), V2 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
    ID = c("rs111768751", "rs2068663", NA, "rs61781371", "rs11206374", 
    NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
```

Comment: In your example, should no occurrences of `BRCA` be left, or should both be removed as they are duplicate and have `ID == NA`? If not, `distinct(data)` might also work.

Comment: Do you want to keep the the output, or remove the output from your dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `dplyr` you could use

```r
df %>%
  add_count(Gene, ID) %>%
  filter(is.na(ID) & n > 1) %>%
  select(-n)
```

to get

```r
   Gene     Score V1 V2   ID 
1: BRCA 0.8972038 NA NA <NA> 
2: BRCA 0.8972038 NA NA <NA>
```

Answer (score 0):

First we put all the NA Id's at the bottom (Not needed with example data, but makes the solution more robust)

```
df <- df[order(df$ID, na.last=T),]
```

Then we removed the duplicated &  ID's

```
df <- df[!(duplicated(df$Gene) & is.na(df$ID)),]
```

Output

```
> df 
    Gene     Score V1 V2          ID
1 PABPC4 0.7972038 NA NA rs111768751
5    ACE 0.8972038 NA NA  rs11206374
2 PABPC4 0.7972038 NA NA   rs2068663
4    ACE 0.8972038 NA NA  rs61781371
6   BRCA 0.8972038 NA NA        <NA>
```